# jQuery dialog form submit to CodeIgniter form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I'm ajax post'ing form data from a jquery dialog modal to my CodeIgniter controller which performs its form validation. Everything works fine when using FireFox.  When using IE10, the form does not seem to submit to the controller. I found suggestions saying to add "contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' to my jquery .ajax - this seems to allow IE10 to start submitting the form, however CI form validation no longer seems to work for either browser. Remarking the contentType out (as per below) allows FireFox to work again.

Any suggestions?

Here's my javascript:

```
var dataObj = {type_id: tt_tid, rtype_id: tt_rtid, ref_id: tt_rid, time: tt_time, date: tt_date };

$.ajax({
    data: dataObj,
    cache:false,
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: '<?php echo base_url();?>task/tt_ajax_add',
    success: function(data) {
        //Clear the message
        $("#modal_message").html('').removeClass().css({'display' : 'none'});

        if (data.success == true) {
            $("#modal_message").html(data.message).css({'display' : 'block'}); 
            clearForm('#m_timetrack_form');
        }else{
            $("#modal_message").html(data.message).addClass('error').css({'display' : 'block'}); 
        }
    }
});
```

Here's my CI controller method

```
function tt_ajax_add()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $validate_config = "timetrack_add";

        //Check if the form is valid
        if ($this->form_validation->run($validate_config) == FALSE ){
            $result['success'] = FALSE;
            $result['message'] = "Please correct any errors below.";
            $result['message'] .= validation_errors();
            //$result['message'] .= file_get_contents('php://input');

        #Form data was valid
        }else{
            $result['success'] = TRUE;
            $result['message'] = "Submitted successfully.";

        }
        exit(json_encode($result));
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: two things, does dataObj return valid JSON once all variables are assigned? and have you tried not using php in the URL like url: '..task/tt_ajax_add',

Comment: yes, it is valid, and i've tried without the php in the url.

Comment: <meta charset="utf-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />   fixed the issue for me.